# React native card view

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to have a card view similar to this -

[image]

This is taken from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-material-cards

The image is full card view and the text info is on a transparent block which contains title text and sub text. I am using the same library for my project but I cannot achieve this transparent block of text on image. How could I do that?

Comment: You can always add a `View` and specify a `backgroundColor` with `opacity` to it.

Comment: Can you show me with an example please

Comment: Can i see the your code for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need 3rd party library, you could achieve this using built-in React-Native component like View, Image, and Text.

I created the quick dirty sample code for you:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Image, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ width: 200, height: 200, flexDirection: 'row', margin: 24 }}>
        <Image
          style={{ width: 200, height: 200, position: 'absolute' }}
          source={{ uri: 'https://www.dike.lib.ia.us/images/sample-1.jpg/image' }}
        />
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)', alignSelf: 'flex-end' }}>
          <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 20, margin: 6 }}>{'Title'}</Text>
          <Text style={{ color: 'white', margin: 6 }}>{'Subtitle'}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Sample Result]

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented CardView for react-native with elevation, that support android(All version) and iOS. https://github.com/Kishanjvaghela/react-native-cardview. Check this out